# The positivity of (co-)tangent bundle of projective bundles.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> [Big Question] Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Consider $p:\mathbb{P}_X(\mathscr{E})\to X$ be a projective bundle in the sense of Grothendieck.
> Is there some useful method to find the positivity of $T_{\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E})}$ or $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E})}$?

In this case we have Euler sequences $0\to \Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E})}\to p^*\mathscr{E}(1)\to\mathscr{O}\to0$ and $0\to\mathscr{O} \to p^*\mathscr{E}^{\vee}(-1)\to T_{\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E})}\to0$. But I don't know how to show whether they are ample/nef/big or not.

Of course by Hartshorne's conjecture (proved by Mori) the only ample tangent bundle appears in projective spaces. By CP-conjecture (still open), maybe the only nef tangent bundle appears in abelian varieties and rational homogeneous varieties, up to an etale covering. So my main question is actually the following:

> [Main Question] For example for projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$, consider $\mathbb{P}(T_{\mathbb{P}^n})$ and $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n})$, are their tangent bundles are nef?

In the first case $\mathbb{P}(T_{\mathbb{P}^n})$, we can show that $\mathbb{P}(T_{\mathbb{P}^n})$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^n$ by Euler sequence. Moreover, we also have $-K_{\mathbb{P}(T_{\mathbb{P}^n})}=\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}(T_{\mathbb{P}^n})}(n)$ which is ample since $T_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ is ample. Hence $\mathbb{P}(T_{\mathbb{P}^n})$ is Fano. Moreover easy to see that $\mathbb{P}(T_{\mathbb{P}^n})$ is actually a partial flag variety $\mathrm{Flag}(1,n;\mathbb{C}^{n+1})$, hence $\mathbb{P}(T_{\mathbb{P}^n})$ is homogeneous as it is $\mathrm{SL}_{n+1}/P(1,n)$. So it has nef tangent bundle but not ample.

But how about $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n})$? In this case $-K_{\mathbb{P}(\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n})}=\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n})}(n)+p^*\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(2n+2)$. I don't even know whether it is Fano or not! Now I believe that its tangent bundle is not nef but I don't know how to prove it! Can we connected it to $\mathbb{P}(T_{\mathbb{P}^n})$? Is there some relation between the tangent/ cotangent bundles of $\mathbb{P}(\scr{E})$ and $\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{E}^{\vee})$?

---

Thank you for your any help!!!

Comment: Actually, $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) \cong \mathrm{Fl}(1,2;n+1)$.

Comment: @Sasha That's looks amazing. Could you give me some hint about this isomorphism? Thank you very much!

Comment: There are many ways to show this. For instance, you can use the $\mathrm{GL}_{n+1}$-action. It acts transitively on the projective space, the bundle $\Omega$ is equivariant, hence the action lifts to its projectivization. Moreover, the stabilizer of a point acts transitively on the projectivization of the fiber of $\Omega$ at that point. Hence the action on the projective bundle is transitive, and it is not hard to identify the stabilizer of a point with the parabolic subgroup of the flag variety.